# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} c^k = \frac{c(c^n-1)}{c-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How would one show that the [summation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation%20from%201%20to%20n%20of%20c%5Ek) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} c^k = \frac{c(c^n-1)}{c-1}$ is true?

Comment: What is $(c-1)\sum_{k=1}^n c^k$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

Suppose $$S = \sum_{k=1}^n c^k \tag{1}$$

$$cS = \sum_{k=1}^n c^{k+1}\tag{2}$$

Use the second expression to subtract the first expression and then solve for $S$.